# Set GCP App Engine firewall rules for each service in the project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP App Engine project that hosts several services. For one of them, I would like to set a firewall to restrict access to only internal IP addresses.

But when I go to the "Firewall rules" page in GCP, it seems that I can only set global firewall rules, not separately for each service. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that in your current architecture. If you are running your microservices under one single App Engine application there is no way that you can differentiate them by any GCP setting.

As it is stated in the official documentation:

> A firewall provides identity-agnostic access control for your App Engine app.

The app is seen and treated as a whole, no metter how many  services are under the blankets. You can read more about how controlling access with firewall rules works, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/creating-firewalls).

The most similar thing that you can do in App Engine is to [restrict access to some specific services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#restricting_access_to_a_service) by adding "login : admin" element to its [handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_login).

As an alternative you can segregate your application and run all you services on [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/). That way you would be able to put each service under certain networks and add/delete firewall rules.